# How to change text and square rectangle on click in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a screenshot as shown below which I have replicated in HTML/CSS.

[image]

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/158/embedded/result/) for the above screenshot. Have used Bootstrap 4 to make rows and tables.

The snippets of HTML and JQuery codes which I have used in the fiddle is:

**HTML:**

```
    <tr>
         <td class="left">Fred Doe's Guest 1</td>
         <td class="number1">250</td>
         <td class="table1">2</td>
         <td class="right-itemswaiting">
         <div class="square-white"></div>
         <span class="items-waiting">Items Waiting</span>
         </td>
   </tr>
```

**JQuery**:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var fold = $("#fold");
    fold.cliked = 1;
    fold.click(function () {
        $(".items-waiting").text((fold.cliked++ % 2 == 0) ? "Items Waiting" : "Items Received");
    });
});
```

The above HTML and JQUery codes are taken from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6paG/). The fold element (2nd line) used in JQuery  is not present in HTML as I am unsure how to use it accurately there.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what I need to add in the JQuery code so that on clicking the  **Items waiting** colored box (marked with arrow in the screenshot), the text should change from **Items waiting** to **Items received**. Also, the **filled white background square box** should be replaced by **unfilled white square box**.

Comment: The first fiddle you provided only use pure Javascript.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory Yes there is no fold element in HTML. I am wondering how to fit that in HTML.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory It JQuery, I am not sure how to enable it in the fiddle.

Comment: There's a dropdown list above the javascript block. Select jQuery in _FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
<span class="items-waiting">Items Waiting</span>
```

to

```
<span id = "fold" class="items-waiting">Items Waiting</span>
```

EDIT: As I can see you want to use more than one elements to be clicked, you need to use class instead of ID... I've updated the fiddle accordingly.

https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/173/

Comment: I tried but for reasons it didn't work. I am wondering if you can update it in the fiddle I have provided.

Comment: Also, In the fiddle, I am not sure how to turn on JQuery Library.

Comment: You need to select jQuery from the dropdown to enable jQuery.

Comment: Hi, I have one quick question. In my pc, the text change happens on double click. Is there any reason for that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168853/discussion-between-khan-and-user5447339).

Comment: Its working fine on the fiddle, but I can still see the issue probably I am using angular.

Answer (score 1):

Apply "fold" id to td that you looking to target or you can apply class name for 
 multiple item and just put following jQuery code.

I used `$(this)` to target only item that clicked not all id/class as "fold"

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fold = $(".mychanger");
    fold.cliked = 1;
    $.fn.textChange = function() {
        
    fold.click(function () {
        $(this).find(".items-waiting").text((fold.cliked++ % 2 == 0) ? "Items Waiting" : "Items Received");
        $(this).find(".square-white").toggleClass("transclass");
    });
    };
    
});
```

```css
    // General CSS
.nav-top-searchbar {
    position: relative;
}

#ellipsis {
    top: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 43px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#ellipsis:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#ellipsis:focus+.dropdown {
    display: block;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    background: #10314c;
}

.dropdown {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    /* padding-left: 2%; */
    position: absolute;
    /* height: 150px; */
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 10;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #888;
    top: 2px;
}

.searchicon {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    left: 8px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 3px;
}

.table td,
.table th {
    border-top: none! important;
    padding-left: 3%;
}

.table thead th {
    border-bottom: none! important;
}

.table td.left {
    padding-right: 32%;
}

.dropdown a {
    color: #676767;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.body-manage-attendees tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.body-manage-attendees .number {
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .table1 {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .table2 {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .status {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-bill {
    padding-left: 1%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1173B7;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-nobill {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-unapid {
    padding-left: 1%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1173B7;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-itemsreceived {
    padding-left: 1%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #10314C;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-itemswaiting {
    padding-left: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #10314C;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-unpaid {
    padding-left: 1%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1173B7;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-top-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0% 2.5%;
    background: rgb(16, 49, 76);
    align-items: center;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: 5%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right-itemsreceived span{
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 5px;
}


.square-white {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.right-itemswaiting span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 1%;
}

.transclass{
  background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body-manage-attendees">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col" class="number">Number</th>
                <th scope="col" class="table2">Table</th>
                <th scope="col" class="status">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Eve Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">4</td>
                <td class="right-itemsreceived">Items Received</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Fred Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">2</td>
                <td class="right-itemsreceived"><div class="square"></div><span>Items Received</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Fred Doe's Guest 1</td>
                <td class="number1">250</td>
                <td class="table1">2</td>
                <td onclick="$(this).textChange();" id="fold" class="mychanger right-itemswaiting"><div class="square-white"></div><span  class="items-waiting">Items Waiting</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Jack Doe</td>
                <td class="number1">14</td>
                <td class="table1">4</td>
                <td class="right-unpaid">Unpaid</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @developer kt I added a click method as I am using angular 5. What I did is `<td id="fold" (click)="textChange()" class="right-itemswaiting">
                    <div class="square-white"></div><span class="items-waiting">Items Waiting</span></td>`

Comment: @developer kt In the ts(typescript), I have called,  `textChange(){  
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fold = $("#fold");
    fold.cliked = 1;
    fold.click(function () {
        $(this).find(".items-waiting").text((fold.cliked++ % 2 == 0) ? "Items Waiting" : "Items Received");
        $(this).find(".square-white").toggleClass("transclass");
    });
});
}` method but for some reasons, the text change happens only once comparatively it should happen again and again.

Comment: The text change happens only once, after hitting the `changed text` again it doesn't go back to the `original text`.

Comment: problem was, when you click , it assign fold.cliked = 1; and then fold.cliked++; so it's geting 2 evry time on click,  and that's why i put both line var fold = $(".mychanger");
    fold.cliked = 1; outside of function

Answer (score 1):

In my view of point, I found that there're serveral things have to be changed.

Not only toggle the `square` but `sibling`'s class `items-waiting` should be removed. And also the class `right-itemswaiting` in `<td>` should change to `right-itemsreceived`.

So this is an example that only works on the square with class `square-white`. After you clicked on it, it changes and wouldn't be triggered again. You can make your version base on this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.square-white', function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.toggleClass('square square-white')
    $this.siblings().removeClass('items-waiting').text('Items Received')
    $this.parent().toggleClass('right-itemswaiting right-itemsreceived')
  })
});
```

```css
// General CSS
.nav-top-searchbar {
  position: relative;
}

#ellipsis {
  top: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 43px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#ellipsis:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#ellipsis:focus+.dropdown {
  display: block;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  background: #10314c;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
  /* padding-left: 2%; */
  position: absolute;
  /* height: 150px; */
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #888;
  top: 2px;
}

.searchicon {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 26px;
  left: 8px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 3px;
}

.table td,
.table th {
  border-top: none ! important;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

.table thead th {
  border-bottom: none ! important;
}

.table td.left {
  padding-right: 32%;
}

.dropdown a {
  color: #676767;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.body-manage-attendees tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.body-manage-attendees .number {
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .table1 {
  padding-left: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .table2 {
  padding-left: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 6%;
}

.body-manage-attendees .status {
  padding-left: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right {
  padding-left: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-bill {
  padding-left: 1%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1173B7;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-nobill {
  padding-left: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-unapid {
  padding-left: 1%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1173B7;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-itemsreceived {
  padding-left: 1%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #10314C;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-itemswaiting {
  padding-left: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #10314C;
}

.body-manage-attendees .right-unpaid {
  padding-left: 1%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1173B7;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-top-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0% 2.5%;
  background: rgb(16, 49, 76);
  align-items: center;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-right: 5%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right-itemsreceived span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.square-white {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: white;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right-itemswaiting span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body-manage-attendees">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col" class="number">Number</th>
        <th scope="col" class="table2">Table</th>
        <th scope="col" class="status">Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td class="left">Eve Doe</td>
        <td class="number1">250</td>
        <td class="table1">4</td>
        <td class="right-itemsreceived">Items Received</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">Fred Doe</td>
        <td class="number1">250</td>
        <td class="table1">2</td>
        <td class="right-itemsreceived">
          <div class="square"></div><span>Items Received</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">Fred Doe's Guest 1</td>
        <td class="number1">250</td>
        <td class="table1">2</td>
        <td class="right-itemswaiting">
          <div class="square-white"></div>
          <span class="items-waiting">Items Waiting</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">Jack Doe</td>
        <td class="number1">14</td>
        <td class="table1">4</td>
        <td class="right-unpaid">Unpaid</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```